# How to run multiple actions using one playbook on a newly created server

Tags: deployment, ansible, filesystems

The server is being created without any issues, but when it comes to the action point of installing fresh vanilla wordpress using the *action* method I get the following error;

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cd /home/catena/ && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar xvf latest.tar.gz && rm latest.tar.gz && chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress", "delta": "0:00:00.002078", "end": "2022-06-23 17:21:19.097106", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2022-06-23 17:21:19.095028", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/catena/", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/catena/"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

I have tested this separately and it worked (the directory `/home/catena/` is there) but the goal is to have it creating the server and downloading the wordpress directory using one playbook

This is my playbook `provision-server.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Create Basic Server
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  check_mode: no
  user: root
  vars:
    hcloud_token: "my_token"
  tasks:
    - name: Create a basic server
      hcloud_server:
          api_token: "my_token"
          name: test-server
          server_type: cpx31
          datacenter: nbg1-dc3
          image: id_image
          state: present
      register: server
    - name: Creating new site dir and installing fresh vanilla wordpress
      action: shell cd /home/catena/ && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar xvf latest.tar.gz && rm latest.tar.gz && chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress
    - name: Naming the new site
      action: shell mv /home/catena/wordpress /home/catena/site_name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible loops over inventory "automagically."  Use that.  Put the server into your inventory:

```ini
[servers]
test-server
```

Now, have your playbook create the servers:

```yaml
---
- name: Create Basic Server
  hosts: servers
  gather_facts: False
  check_mode: no
  user: root
  vars:
    hcloud_token: "my_token"
  tasks:
    - name: Create a basic server
      hcloud_server:
          api_token: "my_token"
          name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          server_type: cpx31
          datacenter: nbg1-dc3
          image: id_image
          state: present
      register: server
      delegate_to: localhost
      become: no

    - name: Creating new site dir and installing fresh vanilla wordpress
      action: shell cd /home/catena/ && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar xvf latest.tar.gz && rm latest.tar.gz && chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress

    - name: Naming the new site
      action: shell mv /home/catena/wordpress /home/catena/site_name
```

Note that we're using `delegate_to: localhost` on the `hcloud_server` task, but not on the others.  Also taken out the `connection: local` option, which will prevent connection to your new servers.

Comment: Using shell when there are available specific modules doing the work for you is a bad practice. Have a look at `get_url` , `unarchive`, `file` and `copy` which can replace all or your above commands in dedicated and idempotent tasks.

Comment: Added the test-server as per suggestion to my inventory but getting `error; fatal: [test-server]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname test-server: Name or service not known", "unreachable": true}` . Still a beginner with ansible but how is it that in my inventory hosts file it will know the IP of the server if it's just been created? BTW the only different thing I did from you was this line; `hosts: servers` to `hosts: test-server` since I don't want to affect the rest of servers

Comment: Your ansible host has to use the hcloud hypervisor as a Domain Name Server.  The hcloud knows what IP addresses it assigns, to avoid creating VMs with the same IP address.